# Button image as a submit button

Tags: html, submit

I'm creating a simple HTML form, with some php code, which captures person data and stores it in a Mysql database.

If I use the following basic code to submit the form it works perfectly:-

```
'''<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add new member"/>'''
```

If I change it to use following code in order to use a image as a button it doesn't work:-

```
'''<input type="image" src="images/button_add-new-member.png" alt="Submit" width="200px" height="28px"  >'''
```

I have seen this is the code on numerous websites and it apparently works. It doesn't for me.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

It should be working. Anyway, if it's not, check if there is a problem on your php file or try this code below:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="www.google.pt" method="POST">
    <button style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Submit" width="200px" height="28px"/>
    </button>
</form>
```

This code does the same thing, but in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

Give your input tag a "name" attribute and access it in php using "isset".